# Get ID of clicked Object which has been created later

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get the ID of clicked element. The element is not created initially, but later.

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub_nav_node', function(event) {                  
    var name = event.target.id + "|Screen"

    alert(name);
});
```

so basically the "event.target.id" is not working for me. I tried the following solutions I found on stack overflow:

```
$(event.target).id 

$(event.target)[0].id

event.target.id

this.id

$(this).id
```

I always used $ ( this ), however i cannot use it in this context since $( ".sub_nav_node" ).click() doesnt work, because the elements are not availalbe initally...

Comment: And does the created node have the correct class of `sub_nav_node`? Does the `alert()` fire at all? What does it show when it alerts? Does the element actually *have* an `id`?

Comment: I assume the element with class `sub_nav_node` also has an `id`, [because I got it to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uofu8jv/3/).

Comment: Then show your HTML; because your first code-block should work as-written, if jQuery's actually included on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is a element with class `sub_nav_node` this should work :

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub_nav_node', function(event) {                  
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: returns undefined - any ideas? - sry works now :D typo

Comment: `undefined` means that, this element doesn't have that attribute